# Verifying triangle inequality for vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector, inequalities

How would I get Mathematica to verify the triangle inequality for norms (say, the 2-norm for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

For scalars, this suffices:

```
Reduce[Abs[x + y] <= Abs[x] + Abs[y], {x, y}, Reals] (* True *)
```

However, I can't get Mathematica to verify `Norm[x + y] <= Norm[x] + Norm[y]` for fixed- or general-dimension vector spaces, using `Reduce` or `Simplify` with appropriate assumptions.

Comment: An even simpler version of this would be verifying that `Norm[x]==0` implies `x` is the zero *vector*.

Answer (score 2):

Directly:

```
x = {a, b};
y = {c, d};
Reduce[Norm[x + y] <= Norm[x] + Norm[y], {a, b, c, d}, Reals]
```

returns `True`. Slightly more generally:

```
x = Array[a, 2];
y = Array[b, 2];
Reduce[Norm[x + y] <= Norm[x] + Norm[y], Flatten@{x, y}, Reals]
```

works, but I grew tired of waiting when I replaced the "2" with a "3". The "simpler version" is indeed simpler, and works for much larger dimensions:

```
x = Array[a, 10];
Solve[Norm[x] == 0, x, Reals]

{{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 0, a[4] -> 0, a[5] -> 0, 
  a[6] -> 0, a[7] -> 0, a[8] -> 0, a[9] -> 0, a[10] -> 0}}
```

Comment: Sure, but this quickly becomes unwieldy and computationally intensive. Ideally I'd like to specify something like `x \[Element] Vectors[10]` or `x \[Element] Vectors[n]`.

Comment: Was just about to post how it works a little better for the simpler example :)...still can't help but feel that Mathematica can do something smarter than try to brute force a polynomial in $2n$ variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can project higher dimensional spaces down to 2D with one vertex at the origin.  In this case:

```
x = {a, b};
y = {c, d};
z = {0, 0};
CylindricalDecomposition[Norm[x - z] + Norm[y - z] >= Norm[x - y], {a, b, c, d}]
(* True *)
```

Comment: The wording is a bit off here. What is true is that a pair of vectors determines a two dimensional space. That is not the same as representing them in two dimensions using the "standard" Cartesian basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Resolve[ForAll[{x, y, u, v}, 
  Simplify[ExpandAll@
     ComplexExpand[
      Abs[x + I y] + Abs[(u + I v)] - Abs[(x + I y) + (u + I v)]], {x,
       y, u, v} \[Element] Reals] >= 0]]
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> How would I get Mathematica to verify the triangle inequality for norms (say, the 2-norm for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

There are many ways to verify this mathematically. One way is to use
[Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

> $$ \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2\right) - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k\right)^2  = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n \left(a_i b_j - a_j b_i\right)^2 $$

The right side is the sum of real squares and therefore nonnegative.
This implies that
$\, (\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})^2 \le ||\vec{x}||^2 ||\vec{y}||^2 \,$
which is almost the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Take square roots to get
$$ \vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}\le|\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}|\le||\vec{x}||\,||\vec{y}||$$
This implies
$$ ||\vec{x}+\vec{y}||^2 = (\vec{x}+\vec{y})\cdot(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) = 
||\vec{x}||^2+||\vec{y}||^2+2(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}) \le \\
||\vec{x}||^2+||\vec{y}||^2+2||\vec{x}||\,||\vec{y}|| =
(||\vec{x}|| + ||\vec{y}||)^2. $$
Take square roots to finally get
$$ ||\vec{x}+\vec{y}||\le ||\vec{x}|| + ||\vec{y}||. $$

Your asked

> However, I can't get Mathematica to verify `Norm[x + y] <= Norm[x] + Norm[y]` for fixed- or general-dimension vector spaces, using `Reduce` or `Simplify` with appropriate assumptions.

Unfortunately, I think it is asking too much of Mathematica *currently*
to be able to do exactly what you requested in general. For $n=2$ it is
not hard. For $n=3$ it is much harder and I think it is hopeless for
anything beyond that. Perhaps future version of Mathematica may be able
to do it.